# Restric user access to table using Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using Sql Server-2008. I need to restrict user access to TABLES (to hide the tables from users). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [DENY object permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173724.aspx).

Your code will look something like this:

```
DENY SELECT ON OBJECT::Person.Address TO RosaQdM;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just tables or all database objects?  If it is just tables, and they don't belong to their own schema, you will be doing it manually (i.e. each table).  But if they are part of the same schema, and you want to also restrict access to on the VIEWs, then you can do something like this:

```
deny select on schema::dbo to YourUserToRestrict
```

This is provided your tables and views are in the `dbo` schema.