# Retrieve Value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have to create a SSRS Report to retrieve the value according to this condition:

- A,B,C,D,E are Five users
  think,
- A as Junior developer
- B as developer
- C as senior developer
- D as project manager
- E as Sr project manager
- A reports to B
- B reports to C
- C reports to D
- D reports to E

Then:

- when A logs in he can only see his records
- when B logs in he can see the records for A,B and not able to see the C,D and E records
- when C logs in he can see the records for A,B,C and not able to see the D and E records
- when D logs in he can see the records for B,C,D and not able to see the A and E records
- and when E logs in he can see the records for C,D,E and not able to see the A,B records

Is there any way to retrieve the value this way?

Comment: More info needed. What are the table relations? Where is this "reports to" relationship saved? How are these records saved in a table?

Comment: Is the logic that a user can see his own records and the records of two levels below him, but never the ones above?

Comment: @Varun upto my understanding you need to create a new table name ReportTo which contain two fields Emp, EmpReportTo Now you can check if Emp:C and EmpReportTo:D and if you find the entry of C in EmpReportTo column then it means D is able to see the profile of Emp of EmpReportTo:C, may be this will help you

Comment: there is a column where the reporting manager is saved, it is done in the employee table but i need to check the report for only two level

Comment: see this one, I hope this will be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970611/restric-user-access-to-table-using-sql-server-2008

Comment: @jpw yes this is the logic

Answer (score 0):

You can try as following...

1. Create ROLE for each user (A,B,C,D)
2. Give permission as your need for each role . For example, B 'ROLE' can access 'B1, B2, B3' tables.

You can also do something like this...

Denying SELECT permission on a table....
The following example denies SELECT permission to the user user1 on the table Person.name in the db1 database.

```
USE db1;
DENY SELECT ON OBJECT::Person.name TO user1;
GO
```

For more information :

1. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173724.aspx
2. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188338.aspx