# admin view documents through department

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

Admin i.e John is linked to HR department when he signup then choose HR department and his data is stored in **userss** table and in this table there id is set as dep id =2 which is dep2.

Then I want when he logs in through his login id and password then he can only access HR documents not other documents like finance, computer science, marketing and I have tried this query.

First I select dep id:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sphrdoc]
@UserName  nvarchar(50),
@Password nvarchar(50)
as
select DepID from Userss where UserName=@UserName AND [Password]=@Password
```

Then I create a function:

```
publicint  hrdoc(string Username,string password)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32( db.ExecuteScalar("sphrdoc",newobject[]  
       {Username,password}));

    }
```

Then in page load:

```
Session["a"] = dd.hrdoc(Convert.ToString(Session["Login2"]),   
(Convert.ToString(Session["Login3"])));
```

Then I set this query:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sphrdocid1]
 @DepID int
as
 SELECT DocumentInfo.DocID,
 dbo.DocumentInfo.DocName,
dbo.DocumentInfo.Uploadfile,
dbo.DocType.DocType,
 dbo.Department.DepType ,
dbo.ApproveType.ApproveType AS ApproveID
FROM dbo.DocumentInfo
left JOIN dbo.DocType ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DocTypeID=dbo.DocType.DocTypeID
left JOIN dbo.Department ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DepID=dbo.Department.DepID
LEFT JOIN dbo.ApproveType ON dbo.ApproveType.approveid=dbo.Department.DepID where   
dbo.Department.DepID=@DepID


public DataTable hrdoc1(int id)
    {           
        DataTable table = db.ExecuteDataSet("sphrdocid1", new object[] { id 
       }).Tables[0];
        return table;

    }
```

Then in page load I call this:

```
GrdFileApprove.DataSource = dd.hrdoc1(Convert.ToInt32(Session["a"]));
          GrdFileApprove.DataBind();
```

But still when John logs in then he can see all documents related to HR, marketing, finance, computer science.

Comment: Do you want to keep access limit to the user (admin) ? So that, he can only access hr related tables?

Comment: YES... he can only access hr related data which is stored in approval table not tables...

Comment: follow this link, I hope, it can solve your issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588327/retrieve-value-in-sql/19589156#19589156

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks correct. You need to check your data to make sure all values are correctly populated.

Is that your actual code you are using? Do you need a left join on the Department table?

```
exec sphrdocid1 @DepID = 1

go
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sphrdocid1]
 @DepID int
as
begin
SELECT DocumentInfo.DocID, dbo.DocumentInfo.DocName, dbo.DocumentInfo.Uploadfile, dbo.DocType.DocType, dbo.Department.DepType , dbo.ApproveType.ApproveType AS ApproveID
FROM dbo.DocumentInfo
JOIN dbo.Department
    ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DepID=dbo.Department.DepID
left JOIN dbo.DocType 
    ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DocTypeID=dbo.DocType.DocTypeID
LEFT JOIN dbo.ApproveType 
    ON dbo.ApproveType.approveid=dbo.Department.DepID 
where  dbo.DocumentInfo.DepID=@DepID
end
```

Comment: its probably your data. did you check your data? how many different departmentids are in the table?